# How to get the string value from the function CountryManager::getStandardList()?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Input :

```
 $li = array();
    $list = \Drupal\Core\Locale\CountryManager::getStandardList();
    foreach($list as $key => $value){
        $li[$key] = $value;
    } 
    // print_r($li);
```

Output :

```
[AF] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup Object
        (
            [string:protected] => Afghanistan
            [translatedMarkup:protected] => Afghanistan
            [options:protected] => Array
                (
                )
```

How can I fetch String value from the above structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fetch the string value from the translatable markup object use type casting:

```
$li[$key] = (string) $value;
```

Comment: Gr8 Answer and very much  helpful for me!!

Answer (score 1):

While you can explicitly cast it to a string as suggested in 4k4's answer, in 99% of the cases, you don't have to.

print_r(), var_dump() and similar will show the object, but when you actually print it out, it will be implicitly cast to a string.

There are only very few cases where you must cast yourself, for example when you want to use the string as an array *key*.

You can pass such an object along in a render array, #options for a select or almost anything else and it will just work.