# How to get the form field label of a multi-value field

Tags: forms

In hook_form_user_form_alter I need to get the title of each field. When I dump a normal (single-value) field #title is an array value, like this:

```
array (size=13)
  '#title' => string 'Name' (length=13)
  '#title_display' => string 'before' (length=6)
```

but for fields that can contain more than one value, #title is an object that looks like this:

```
array (size=13)
  '#title' => 
    object(Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup)[1544]
      protected 'translatedMarkup' => null
      protected 'options' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'stringTranslation' => 
        object(Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager)[285]
          protected 'translators' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'sortedTranslators' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'defaultLangcode' => string 'en' (length=2)
          public '_serviceId' => string 'string_translation' (length=18)
      protected 'string' => string '@title (value @number)' (length=22)
      protected 'arguments' => 
        array (size=2)
          '@title' => string 'Name' (length=19)
          '@number' => int 1
  '#title_display' => string 'invisible' (length=9)
  '#description' => string '' (length=0)
  '#field_parents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '#required' => boolean false
  '#delta' => int 0
  '#weight' => int 0
  '#type' => string 'textfield' (length=9)
  '#default_value' => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
  '#size' => int 60
  '#placeholder' => string '' (length=0)
  '#maxlength' => int 255
  '#attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'class' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'js-text-full' (length=12)
          1 => string 'text-full' (length=9)
```

If I just refer to #title, for the multi-value field I end up with:

```
Name (value 1)
```

What is the proper way of obtaining the title, and what causes the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper way of obtaining the title, and what causes the
>   difference?

The cause is this code in the field widget:

```
  // For multiple fields, title and description are handled by the wrapping
  // table.
  if ($is_multiple) {
    $element = [
      '#title' => $this->t('@title (value @number)', ['@title' => $title, '@number' => $delta + 1]),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
      '#description' => '',
    ];
```

This [t($string, array $args = [], array $options = [])](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/function/StringTranslationTrait%3A%3At/8.7.x) function returns a [TranslatableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/class/TranslatableMarkup/8.7.x) object.

You can cast the translatable markup as string to obtain the title, but normally you don't have to. See both answers here  [How to get the string value from the function CountryManager::getStandardList()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192360/how-to-get-the-string-value-from-the-function-countrymanagergetstandardlist)

Comment: If you look at the @ string property, it is what I receive when I cast (string)$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['#title'] as suggested at that link. I see further down an @ arguments with a @title property that does not contain 'value @ number', but am unclear how to get to it.

Comment: The answer given is correct in terms of the cause. The way I found to get to just the label without the value suffix is: $form[field]['widget'][0]['#title']->getArguments()['@title']